# eclipse plugin development --add predefined sub folders in a Project when selecting a wizard

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am a beginner to eclipse plugin development.Actually i was trying to make a wizard in NEW->OTHERS. Say NEW->OTHERS->XYZenterprise (category)and a wizard in it XYZproject.I have done this.

What i am struggling with is ,that when i click XYZproject a page opens and it ask project name and when u click finish it adds that project with the specified name in the workspace.i achieved this by creating a class and extending it with BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.

**like this:-
import org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.*;
"public class NewWizard1 extends BasicNewProjectResourceWizard {"**

Upto this point i am able to achieve what is required.
**What i want is when i click finish ,it add project with the name specified in the workspace but also with some folders with predefined names as sub folders in project.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with using `BasicNewProjectResourceWizard` is that the `performFinish` creates the project and immediately shows it before you have a chance to add the extra folders. Unfortunately this is not easy to change so many of the new wizards don't use it.

If you do use this wizard, you could override `performFinish` and add the folder creates there:

```
@Override
public boolean performFinish()
{
  if (!super.performFinish())
    return false;

  IProject newProject = getNewProject();

  IFolder newFolder = newProject.getFolder(new Path("relative path for folder"));

  newFolder.create(false, true, progress monitor);

  return true;
}
```

If you are creating a lot of folders you may want to use an `WorkspaceModifyOperation` or `WorkspaceJob` to show progress during the create.

Comment: Thankyou greg it perfectly works.But i will appreciate if you can tell me the correct way to do it ,as using **BasicNewProjectResourceWizard** might not be handy.

Comment: Doing it properly is long and complicated and requires looking through the BasicNewProjectResourceWizard source.

Comment: Ok what other way i can achieve all this.If i dont use BasicNewProjectResourceWizard

Comment: cannot directly invoke the abstract method performFinish() for the type Wizard !?

Comment: @AhmedLAATABI Sorry but I don't understand, if you have a question about this ask a new Question.

Comment: @greg-449 when i try your solution, i get that Eclipse error at the first code block where you call super.performFinish() !

Comment: @greg-449 i know, and my class is extending Wizard and implementing INewWizard, but get the error : "cannot directly invoke the abstract method performFinish() for the type Wizard" , is this anormal ? should i open a new question ?

Comment: Sorry, yes if you just extend Wizard you don't want the super call. This code was based on something extending `BasicNewProjectResourceWizard` which does the basic project creation.